# MySQL JOIN subquery ON FALSE. Will subquery execute?

Tags: mysql, join

Consider this MySQL query

`SELECT <cols> FROM <tbl> INNER|LEFT JOIN (SELECT ...) AS sub_query ON FALSE`

Of course this will yield an empty result set no matter what's in *tbl* or *sub_query* because of the `ON` statement is always false.

In my situation the only part I can control is the ON statement.

My question is, is MySQL smart enough to detect that? And then skips running the subquery altogether and return the empty result set immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could just test this out:

```
mysql> explain select * from mdl_user join (select 1) q on false;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra            |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | NULL  | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | Impossible WHERE |
|  2 | DERIVED     | NULL  | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | No tables used   |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from mdl_user join (select 1) q on false;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

That would seem to indicate that yes, MySQL detects the `on false` condition, and doesn't bother with the entire join.

(sorry, a moodle database was what I was buried in at the time)

Comment: I've encountered such case in MariaDB 10.6.5 just now and found out that LEFT JOIN leads to full table scan, while JOIN leads to "Impossible WHERE" and no rows returned.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

I would be surprised if MySQL were smart enough *in practice* to do this on a real query.  You should test on your own data.

However, the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html) suggests that it is a possibility:

> For non-EXPLAIN queries, delay of materialization may result in not
>   having to do it at all. Consider a query that joins the result of a
>   subquery in the FROM clause to another table: If the optimizer
>   processes that other table first and finds that it returns no rows,
>   the join need not be carried out further and the optimizer can
>   completely skip materializing the subquery.